# Script to transact tokens on the Polygon chain?

Tags: python, ethereum, polygon, web3py, erc20

I like to automatically transfer funds from all my Metamask wallets into one central wallet automatically on the Polygon chain. How exactly do I do this? Currently I don't how to exactly approach this as the token I'd like to transact is on the polygon chain and I've only seen implementations for the Ethereum chain. This is the token: https://polygonscan.com/token/0x3a9A81d576d83FF21f26f325066054540720fC34

Also don't see an ABI there. It is still an ERC20 token, but I don't know how the implementation differs from a regular token on the Ethereum chain. Currently this is my code for just checking balance, but that doesn't work either as the contract address is not recognized. The error says: "Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

```
from ethtoken.abi import EIP20_ABI

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/..."))

contract_address = '0x3a9A81d576d83FF21f26f325066054540720fC34'
contract  = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=EIP20_ABI)
print(contract.address)

n1 = '0x...'

raw_balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(n1).call()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong **RPC url** for **Polygon Mainnet**.

if you are using infura, then it should be like this:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://polygon.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID"))
```

or you can use public RPC url:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://polygon-rpc.com/"))
```